# order items by specific condition then the rest

Tags: mysql, sql

I want users to see the trending posts first then the rest of the post ordered chronologically.

Here is what my posts table looks like :

```
+----+---------+----------+-------+
| id |  title  | trending | date  |
+----+---------+----------+-------+
|  1 | title_1 |        0 | 1-nov |
|  2 | title_2 |        1 | 2-nov |
|  3 | title_3 |        1 | 3-nov |
|  4 | title_4 |        0 | 4-nov |
|  5 | title_5 |        1 | 5-nov |
+----+---------+----------+-------+
```

For this example the users should see (5->3->2->4->1)

This is what my sql querie looks like so far :

```
SELECT *  FROM cards WHERE trending = 1 ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: What is the type of your `date` column?  Is it just plain text, or something else?  I don't see a year component there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
select * from card order by trending desc, date desc
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a10b2d0e312f77a7bdfcc4f5e10d9b72)**:

```
id | title   | trending | date      
-: | :------ | -------: | :---------
 5 | title_5 |        1 | 2019-11-05
 3 | title_3 |        1 | 2019-11-03
 2 | title_2 |        1 | 2019-11-02
 4 | title_4 |        0 | 2019-11-04
 1 | title_1 |        0 | 2019-11-01
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use two column for order, you will get first result based on trending  = 1 and then by date

```
SELECT *  FROM cards ORDER BY trending DESC, date DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write this query simply.

```
SELECT * from cards 
ORDER BY trending desc, date desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have to tweak your current SQL code a little bit like this:

```
SELECT * FROM CARD 
ORDER BY Trending DESC,DATE DESC
```

**Result:**

[image]